.NET service high memory usage analysis with WinDbg
I came across one problem about high memory usage of one web service running on Azure cloud which is written in .Net4.8. The monitor tool alerts the memory peak reaches to 1.4GB. And I dump the process's memory with tool of ProcDump. The dump file is roughly 1.5GB.
Then I started to analyze the dump file with WinDbg, ok? I did two analysis.
First, I run dumpheap –stat command, which generates the following output. The output is thousands of line long, so I only show a few lines here:
0:000> !dumpheap -stat
Statistics:
              MT    Count    TotalSize Class Name
00007ffce8b30b50        1           24 System.Runtime.Caching.UsageEntryRef
00007ffce8b30ae8        1           24 System.Runtime.Caching.ExpiresEntryRef
00007ffce8b2edc0        1           24 System.Runtime.Caching.ChangeMonitor[]
00007ffce742ae98        1           24 System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.RangeAttribute+<>c
00007ffce742ae50        1           24 System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.RegularExpressionAttribute+<>c
00007ffce742ae08        1           24 System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.RequiredAttribute+<>c
00007ffce742adc0        1           24 System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.StringLengthAttribute+<>c
00007ffce742ad30        1           24 System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationAttribute+<>c
... omit the following part

Based on my investigation, !dumpheap -stat shows the managed heap size. In my case is roughly 45MB(I sum up all the lines above).
Secondly, I run the command !address -summary, then it generates the following output. I paste all the content here
0:000> !address -summary

                                     
Mapping file section regions...
Mapping module regions...
Mapping PEB regions...
Mapping TEB and stack regions...
Mapping heap regions...
Mapping page heap regions...
Mapping other regions...
Mapping stack trace database regions...
Mapping activation context regions...

--- Usage Summary ---------------- RgnCount ----------- Total Size -------- %ofBusy %ofTotal
Free                                    338     7ffe`d06bb000 ( 127.995 TB)          100.00%
<unknown>                              4715        0`feb0f000 (   3.980 GB)  83.90%    0.00%
Stack                                   276        0`16880000 ( 360.500 MB)   7.42%    0.00%
Image                                  1241        0`0e989000 ( 233.535 MB)   4.81%    0.00%
Heap                                    519        0`0b997000 ( 185.590 MB)   3.82%    0.00%
Other                                    15        0`001cd000 (   1.801 MB)   0.04%    0.00%
TEB                                      92        0`000b8000 ( 736.000 kB)   0.01%    0.00%
PEB                                       1        0`00001000 (   4.000 kB)   0.00%    0.00%

--- Type Summary (for busy) ------ RgnCount ----------- Total Size -------- %ofBusy %ofTotal
MEM_PRIVATE                            5051        1`1e9d4000 (   4.478 GB)  94.41%    0.00%
MEM_IMAGE                              1753        0`1013b000 ( 257.230 MB)   5.30%    0.00%
MEM_MAPPED                               55        0`00e26000 (  14.148 MB)   0.29%    0.00%

--- State Summary ---------------- RgnCount ----------- Total Size -------- %ofBusy %ofTotal
MEM_FREE                                338     7ffe`d06bb000 ( 127.995 TB)          100.00%
MEM_RESERVE                            2503        0`cdc3c000 (   3.215 GB)  67.78%    0.00%
MEM_COMMIT                             4356        0`61cf9000 (   1.528 GB)  32.22%    0.00%

--- Protect Summary (for commit) - RgnCount ----------- Total Size -------- %ofBusy %ofTotal
PAGE_READWRITE                         3018        0`50f9f000 (   1.265 GB)  26.67%    0.00%
PAGE_EXECUTE_READ                       128        0`09dbe000 ( 157.742 MB)   3.25%    0.00%
PAGE_READONLY                           663        0`05389000 (  83.535 MB)   1.72%    0.00%
PAGE_WRITECOPY                          281        0`011ef000 (  17.934 MB)   0.37%    0.00%
PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE                   97        0`0072b000 (   7.168 MB)   0.15%    0.00%
PAGE_READWRITE | PAGE_GUARD              92        0`00192000 (   1.570 MB)   0.03%    0.00%
PAGE_EXECUTE_WRITECOPY                   51        0`0014d000 (   1.301 MB)   0.03%    0.00%
PAGE_NOACCESS                            26        0`0001a000 ( 104.000 kB)   0.00%    0.00%

--- Largest Region by Usage ----------- Base Address -------- Region Size ----------
Free                                    21c`92440000     7dd9`6cbe0000 ( 125.849 TB)
<unknown>                               21b`a3b45000        0`0fffb000 ( 255.980 MB)
Stack                                    45`82800000        0`003f9000 (   3.973 MB)
Image                                  7ffc`d3011000        0`011df000 (  17.871 MB)
Heap                                    21c`77d51000        0`00fce000 (  15.805 MB)
Other                                   21b`e6ae0000        0`00181000 (   1.504 MB)
TEB                                      45`80e00000        0`00002000 (   8.000 kB)
PEB                                      45`80f5e000        0`00001000 (   4.000 kB)


Based on my investigation, !address -summary command generates all the memory usage of the .NET process. But this output is really confusing to me!
Can anyone help me to interpret this output? I want to know where the 1.4GB memory is from, for example, managed heap, native heap, stack or assemblies. What kind of analyze can I run next?
Updated
I did some further investigation based on this stackoverflow post: How to find what is in unmanaged memory in Dump by WinDBG
--- Usage Summary ---------------- RgnCount ----------- Total Size -------- %ofBusy %ofTotal
Free                                    338     7ffe`d06bb000 ( 127.995 TB)          100.00%
<unknown>                              4715        0`feb0f000 (   3.980 GB)  83.90%    0.00%
Stack                                   276        0`16880000 ( 360.500 MB)   7.42%    0.00%
Image                                  1241        0`0e989000 ( 233.535 MB)   4.81%    0.00%
Heap                                    519        0`0b997000 ( 185.590 MB)   3.82%    0.00%
Other                                    15        0`001cd000 (   1.801 MB)   0.04%    0.00%
TEB                                      92        0`000b8000 ( 736.000 kB)   0.01%    0.00%
PEB                                       1        0`00001000 (   4.000 kB)   0.00%    0.00%

Free: Is memory that can potentially be claimed from the operating system. This many include swap space, not only physical RAM. In my case is 127.995 TB. This is super big. Let's assume the Azure cloud cluster has a super big disk.
Unknown: Any other heap managers that implements their own memory management. It includes, but is not limited to the managed heap of .NET. In my case is 3.980 GB. This confuses me a lot, since it conflict the 45MB managed heap size of .NET based on the first output above. And it  is even bigger than the actual 1.4GB memory usage.
Heap:  So, what you see as Heap that is memory which was allocated through the Windows Heap manager. On your level of understanding, that's the native heap. In my case this is 185.590MB
Stack: Well that's obvious I think. In my case this part is 360.500MB.
Update 2:
I roughly understand the confusing 3.98GB unknown memory. It turned out that the memory can have 3 different states in the context of WinDbg. They are:
MEM_COMMIT represents memory that has been allocated and backed by physical memory or the paging file.
MEM_FREE refers to unallocated memory that is available for future use.
MEM_RESERVE represents memory that has been reserved in the virtual address space but has not yet been committed.
and the !address -summary generates the following output section based on the memory state as follows:
--- State Summary ---------------- RgnCount ----------- Total Size -------- %ofBusy %ofTotal
MEM_FREE                                338     7ffe`d06bb000 ( 127.995 TB)          100.00%
MEM_RESERVE                            2503        0`cdc3c000 (   3.215 GB)  67.78%    0.00%
MEM_COMMIT                             4356        0`61cf9000 (   1.528 GB)  32.22%    0.00%

The reserved and committed memory adds to 3.215 GB + 1.528 GB = 4.7GB. This is roughly equal to 3.980 GB(unknown) + 360.500 MB(stack) + 233.535 MB(Image) + 185.590 MB(Heap) = 4.7GB. Right?
And the 1.528 GB committed memory is roughly equal to the dump file size and the actual memory usage of the process. Ok?
This means that in that 3.98GB unknown memory segment, most of them are reserved.
Update 3:
As mentioned above, I need to focus on the committed memory type. And thanks to the powerful !address command, which can analyze the memory by filters. For example,
!address -f:MEM_COMMIT -c:".echo %1 %3 %5 %7"

This command will output all the committed memory region, and for each region prints its base address(%1), region size(%3), state(%5) and type(%7). The output goes as follows:
0x5f3a0000 0x1000 MEM_COMMIT Image
0x5f3a1000 0x2ab000 MEM_COMMIT Image
0x5f64c000 0xb000 MEM_COMMIT Image
0x5f657000 0x1b000 MEM_COMMIT Image
0x5f672000 0x2000 MEM_COMMIT Image
0x5f674000 0x2d000 MEM_COMMIT Image
0x7ffe0000 0x1000 MEM_COMMIT Other
0x4580ca7000 0x5000 MEM_COMMIT Stack
...thousands of lines omitted...

And parse all the output with a script(maybe there are some fancy windbg plugins can do that too), get the following memory usages by type:
Memory by Type:
type: Image 233.52344MB
type: Other 1.8007812MB
type: Stack 3.796875MB
type: TEB 0.71875MB
type: PEB 0.00390625MB
type: Heap 84.88281MB
type: <unknown> 1240.2461MB


Unless there are out of memory exceptions, 1.4-GB memory usage is normal and I don't think there is anything to troubleshoot yet. To learn how to interpret WinDbg output, you might find Tess's old blog posts useful, https://www.tessferrandez.com/postindex/ If you want visualization of the memory usage, there are commercial or free memory profilers.

To better understand where the high memory consumption is, it is necessary to run benchmarks or a profiler to perform a detailed analysis of this consumption.
Sometimes it can be "small" code improvements that bring greater performance. (How to use "IENumerable" instead of "List" in scenarios where it is not necessary to iterate the values).
Perhaps a simple solution would be to use a code analyzer such as SonarQube to see what improvements it finds.
